# Please create a standard, explanatory tag wiki for the [untagged] tag

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki, untagged-questions

[Sometimes, questions get the tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167880/1278220) [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged).

And [dozens](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) [of](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) [such](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) [questions](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) languish on many sites in this state for *ages*. ([A review queue was once suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144131/review-task-for-untagged-questions), though it doesn't seem to have gone anywhere.)

When users somehow stumble onto these questions, they see the [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) tag. Except for the fact that it's always a standalone tag and there's never a wiki, it looks just like a normal tag. That feels a bit weird.

So, please create a helpful tag wiki that:

1. explains what the tag is for, and
2. directs the user to edit the questions and retag them as necessary.

(And maybe lock the wiki to prevent edits)

This solution was offered [more than ten years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/111512/1278220), but it was an answer to a different feature-request.  The author of that answer, @[Yi Jiang](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/150097/yi-jiang), wrote what looks to me like a pretty good draft; here's a somewhat edited version:

> **Excerpt:**
>
> > Eek! These poor questions have lost all of their tags- please help by retagging them.
>
> **Body:**
>
> > Most low-activity tags that exist on only one question are automatically pruned after six months. A question that loses all its tags to this process is magically retagged with the [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) tag. Questions may also receive this tag if they were migrated here from another site.
> >
> > Please edit these questions to add relevant tags; consider voting to close and/or delete them if they are off-topic.

Adding a few helpful links in the wiki would also be helpful, though this pretty much explains the important parts.

Comment: I think the excerpt should start with all caps, like "PLEASE RETAG THIS QUESTION".  This is one instance where _shouting_ is warranted because we want it to stand out, and it does stand out.

Comment: The excerpt seems like it might be too confusing, especially to new users. Also, keep in mind that the most common source of [untagged] questions is migration from one site to another (when the original only had tags that don't exist on the destination site, and it's not meta).

Comment: I guess the real question is, is it possible for the system to always create the tag excerpt & wiki every time this tag is created, or preserve them even if the tag is gone? Otherwise, there's a possibility of [the wiki getting orphaned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148927/241919) too many times every time the tag is "fixed" (read: burninated).

Comment: @Laurel - I guess it may be confusing; do you have a suggested re-wording? Also, can you please clarify: What exactly does migration have to do with creating this wiki?

Comment: @Meta Andrew T. - Yeah, I was thinking about that earlier. I think it's certainly _possible_ for them to get this to work, but who knows whether it'll be considered worth it.

Comment: [Untagged] is used as a placeholder on many migrated questions. See for example [this former law question](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/603086/revisions) (and look who edited it lol!). The original tags were [us-federal-government], [interpretation], [executive]; none of those exist on ELU (apparently [interpretation] which we have as a tag synonym doesn't count for this).

Comment: @Laurel - right, but how does that affect having an explanatory wiki? (Just before the 'federal case' q was migrated, the tags on Law.SE were [united-states] + [law-in-fiction] + [executive] i.e., [interpretation] was removed before it got migrated)

Comment: It's just that in the explanation you have, there's no mention of untagged migrated questions, even though that's the majority.